# Problemas al instalar flask y librerías

Tags: python, flask

Tengo una pequeña duda respecto a la instalación de [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) y sus librerías, aclaro que soy [no0b](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q718943) en python. Tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar `flask/bin/pip install flask`, me aparece:

```
bash: flask/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: Parece ser que no has creado el entorno virtual o si lo creaste no está activado. Agrega el sistema operativo, la versión de Python y la versión de VirtualEnv que estás usando.

Comment: Creé el entorno con python3 -m venv flask, tengo ambas versiones de python, 2.7 y 3.4, estoy trabajando en elementary OS freya.

Comment: Bueno, en fin.. resolví esto usando virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv, al parecer el otro método no ponía todos los archivos en el directorio bin.

Comment: Annon, ¿pip lo ejecutas dentro de /bin del folder /flask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estás siguiendo ['The Flask mega tutorial' de Miguel Grinberg](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

La parte de la instalación puede ser un poco confusa. Primero crea un entorno virtual e instala bibliotecas sin llegar a activarlo perdiendo parte de la gracia de usar un entorno virtual. Siguiendo un poco la primera parte del tutorial pero haciéndolo de forma más canónica sería:

Lo siguiente crea un entorno virtual llamado [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) en la ruta en la que te encuentres. Hay otras formas de hacerlo como se indica en el tuturial.

`python -m venv flask`

Una vez que has creado el entorno virtual lo puedes activar. Esto es lo que no hace en su tutorial Miguel Grinberg:

```
. flask/bin/activate # o 'source flask/bin/activate', para Linux y MacOS
```

o

```
flask\\bin\\activate.bat # si estás en windows
```

Ahora que ya lo tienes activado (si todo ha ido bien) deberías poder instalar todas las librerías que te indica sin necesidad de indicar toda la ruta a `pip`:

```
pip install flask
pip install flask-login
pip install flask-openid
pip install flask-mail
pip install flask-sqlalchemy
pip install sqlalchemy-migrate
pip install flask-whooshalchemy
pip install flask-wtf
pip install flask-babel
pip install guess_language
pip install flipflop
pip install coverage
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes instalado [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) simplemente ejecuta:

```
$ pip install Flask
```

revisa la [documentación](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/).